# How to pre load all locales into angular dynamic locale cache (tmhDynamicLocaleCache)

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular dynamic locale (tmhDynamicLocale), but want all my locales to be pre loaded into the cache (tmhDynamicLocaleCache) when the app starts. The motivation behind this is to have all my resources bundled into 1 minified js file rather than the standard lazy loading. Is there a full example for this anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it.
What i did was to put each locale into a module like so:

```
angular.module("myapp.locale.en", [
'tmh.dynamicLocale'
])

.run(['tmhDynamicLocaleCache', function (tmhDynamicLocaleCache) {
    var PLURAL_CATEGORY = {ZERO: "zero", ONE: "one", TWO: "two", FEW: "few", MANY: "many", OTHER: "other"};

    function getDecimals(n) {
        n = n + '';
        var i = n.indexOf('.');
        return (i == -1) ? 0 : n.length - i - 1;
    };

    function getVF(n, opt_precision) {
        var v = opt_precision;

        if (undefined === v) {
            v = Math.min(getDecimals(n), 3);
        }

        var base = Math.pow(10, v);
        var f = ((n * base) | 0) % base;
        return {v: v, f: f};
    };

    tmhDynamicLocaleCache.put('en', {
        "DATETIME_FORMATS": {
            "AMPMS": [
                "AM",
                "PM"
            ],
            "DAY": [
                "Sunday",
                "Monday",
                "Tuesday",
                "Wednesday",
                "Thursday",
                "Friday",
                "Saturday"
            ],
            "FIRSTDAYOFWEEK": 6,
            "MONTH": [
                "January",
                "February",
                "March",
                "April",
                "May",
                "June",
                "July",
                "August",
                "September",
                "October",
                "November",
                "December"
            ],
            "SHORTDAY": [
                "Sun",
                "Mon",
                "Tue",
                "Wed",
                "Thu",
                "Fri",
                "Sat"
            ],
            "SHORTMONTH": [
                "Jan",
                "Feb",
                "Mar",
                "Apr",
                "May",
                "Jun",
                "Jul",
                "Aug",
                "Sep",
                "Oct",
                "Nov",
                "Dec"
            ],
            "WEEKENDRANGE": [
                5,
                6
            ],
            "fullDate": "EEEE, MMMM d, y",
            "longDate": "MMMM d, y",
            "medium": "MMM d, y h:mm:ss a",
            "mediumDate": "MMM d, y",
            "mediumTime": "h:mm:ss a",
            "short": "M/d/yy h:mm a",
            "shortDate": "M/d/yy",
            "shortTime": "h:mm a"
        },
        "NUMBER_FORMATS": {
            "CURRENCY_SYM": "$",
            "DECIMAL_SEP": ".",
            "GROUP_SEP": ",",
            "PATTERNS": [
                {
                    "gSize": 3,
                    "lgSize": 3,
                    "maxFrac": 3,
                    "minFrac": 0,
                    "minInt": 1,
                    "negPre": "-",
                    "negSuf": "",
                    "posPre": "",
                    "posSuf": ""
                },
                {
                    "gSize": 3,
                    "lgSize": 3,
                    "maxFrac": 2,
                    "minFrac": 2,
                    "minInt": 1,
                    "negPre": "\u00a4-",
                    "negSuf": "",
                    "posPre": "\u00a4",
                    "posSuf": ""
                }
            ]
        },
        "id": "en",
        "pluralCat": function (n, opt_precision) {
            var i = n | 0;
            var vf = getVF(n, opt_precision);
            if (i == 1 && vf.v === 0) {
                return PLURAL_CATEGORY.ONE;
            }
            return PLURAL_CATEGORY.OTHER;
        }
    });
}])
;
```

Create a module like this for each locale you use, just change "en" to "pt" or "he" etc (3 places in the code above).

Next load these modules into your app.js...

```
angular.module('myapp', [
'myapp.locale.en',
'myapp.locale.pt',
'myapp.locale.de',
'myapp.locale.he'
])
```

This way when .run() is called on each of these modules it will put the locale object into the tmhDynamicLocaleCache. Then when you later use tmhDynamicLocale.set('en') it will find the locale object in the cache and use it.

Comment: We had to apply this due to our code loading in English shortdates, dates, numbers before the asynchronous call loaded in the 'angular-locale-{{locale}}.js' files. Proved to be pretty much the solution. However, we had to make our 'i18nLanguageService' module to have these newly created locale modules (in your case 'myapp.locale.en') as dependencies, which would force the tmhDynamicLocaleCache be populated before being used. Thanks for leading to the solution!